# Risks in Migrating from XML to JSON

Tags: json, xml

I understand that this question might get flagged as not having an appropriate format for this site, but I wanted to know about the possible risks that one might encounter while deciding to migrate the messaging format from XML to JSON in a data exchange environment.

What criteria one must take into account before making a decision to pursue such overhaul?

Factors such as: complexity of data structures, validation requirements, security, etc. How would a system architect go about such analysis?

Comment: As you say, SO doesn't encourage deeper questions about software engineering - it focusses on narrow coding concerns. Try the xml-dev mailing list, where broad philosophical debates are the primary topic.

Comment: @MichaelKay Thank you. I will surely do that. Are there other forum/mailing lists that you recommend relevant to **XML** and **JSON** discussion?